# qt status bar center align?

Tags: qt, alignment, qstatusbar

How can I center align the text in QStatusBar?
By default it is always left aligned.

I know I can add a QLabel and set alignment, but I want to use plain text, and .showMessage(QString, int) method, so I can add the timeout value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A QStatusBar has three functions of note here:

`addPermanentWidget` - Places a widget right aligned

`addWidget` - Places a widget left aligned which can be obscured by status messages

`showMessage` - Displays a status message

These are well established standards for status bars. While you could hack away to get what you're looking for, I'd suggest you reconsider your needs. Perhaps your QLabel should be placed with addPermanentWidget instead?

Take a look at the docs for more info: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstatusbar.html

Comment: ok. but how can I add the timeout if I use addPermanenetWidget?

Comment: With QTimer.
start it with singleshot when display message on qlabel, and create simply function which cleans label text on timeout.

Comment: @ZolaKt: What do you mean? Are you trying to display the temporary text in a QLabel? Why not just use the showMessage function as it was intended?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to display the temporary text. I am using the showMessage function. I'd just like the text to be center aligned,  instead of default left

Comment: If your concern is that it overwrites the other widgets, then those widgets should probably be placed with addPermanentWidget.
If you just want it in the middle for the sake of it... ugh. And don't expect to use showMessage.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to center the message itself in the whole statusBar, go like this:

```
QLabel* statusLabel = new QLabel("Your Message");
statusBar()->addWidget(statusLabel,1);
```

This additional parameter 1 stretches your Label to the complete width of the statusbar.

Greetings